# Why is Moment JS setting Milliseconds

Tags: date, momentjs

I am trying to create a moment object from string which contains date in format DD/MM/YYYY. I want to set this to be DD/MM/YYYY 23:30. For this, I am writing the code as

```
moment.utc('30/04/2016','DD/MM/YYYY').hours(23).minutes(30)
```

However, that for some reason sets the milliseconds to 300. I am unable to set milliseconds to 0 even using the code below

```
moment.utc('30/04/2016','DD/MM/YYYY').hours(23).minutes(30).milliseconds(0)
```

I only need my date to be like 30/04/2016 23:30:00 and not like 30/04/2016 23:30:00:300

Please see [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhdd8/35/)

Why is the millisecond part being set to 300 and if why am I not able to set it to 0?

Comment: Are you trying to get a time, or a duration? Based on your fiddle, it looks like you are trying to get the number of milliseconds between two dates. You would do this using Moment's duration capabilities, not by creating another moment.

Comment: In addition, moment.utc('30/04/2016','DD/MM/YYYY').hours(23).minutes(30).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS') results in zero milliseconds for me in chrome. It would help to know your browser if you really aren't seeing that.

Comment: You are right Maggie Pint, I realized I was just using a wrong format to get the milliseconds. Apologies, I was using 'ms' instead of 'SSS', don't know where I picked that from. My real issue was that we are using moment.endOf which is setting the milliseconds component to 999. All we need to do is to set that to 0

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
moment.utc('30/04/2016 23:30:00 0','DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss SSS')
```

See this http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/ & http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Comment: I don't need it to only display but want the actual moment object to have a date with zero milliseconds.

Comment: Actually, I don't have much flexibility around the dateformat that comes in, it will be DD/MM/YYYY. So I need to set milliseconds after the moment object is created. Why doesn't the set milliseconds not work?

Comment: @devSuper I don't understand if you have `DD/MM/YYYY` & you are actually setting `hours(23).minutes(30)` so always you can do it this way `moment.utc('30/04/2016 23:30:00 0','DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss SSS')` now why setting `milliseconds` doesn't work I didn't look at that yet with this little time

Comment: @devSuper it's working you have to set `format` http://jsfiddle.net/amrana83/63vvo1vz/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    <body>

<p>Click the button to display date</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date();
        var n=moment.utc('30/04/2016','DD/MM/YYYY').hours(23).minutes(30).seconds(0).milliseconds(0).format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss.SSS');      
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
</script>

</body>
```

working fiddler,
http://jsfiddle.net/fhdd8/356/

Comment: This has the same issue as Arif's answer below. This would only display the date without ms component but I want the actual date to have ms as 0. Because I am using this date to compare with other dates further in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Well u can set time according to your choice by default .now() add upto millisecond.

```
var datetime = moment().set({ hour: 10, minute: 22, second : 19 , millisecond : 999 });
var datetime2 = moment().hour(23).minute(2).second(20);
var time3 = moment('23:11:22.322', "LTS.SSS", true);

datetime.format(LTS.SSS);
datetime2.format(LTS);
datetime.format("hh:mm:ss.SSS")
```

LTS - Localized formats

Time    LT  8:30 PM

Time with seconds   LTS 8:30:25 PM

SSS - Milisecond*s

For display use **format()**